# React: How to set variable in App.js from Stack.Screen component?

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I basically want to change `isSignedIn` value when the user successfully signs in in the screen `SignInScreen`

```
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {
        isSignedIn ? (
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        ) : (
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        )
      }
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

`SignInScreen.jsx`:

```
const submitLogin = async () => {         
        try {
            const data = await axios.post(apiUrl, {username: email, password: password, auth: auth})
            const token = data.data.data.jwt
            //I need to change isSignedIn to true from App.js here             
        }
        catch (err) {
            setMessage('Invalid credentials. Please try again.')
        }
    }
```

Am I thinking this correctly?

Comment: Does this help? [https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen)

Answer (score 0):

> There are multiple ways to handle it you can use React context, 3rd party library called redux, flex, etc. But they need some setup so I use the callback method here.

```
 import {useState} from "react";
 const App=()=>{
  
  const [isSignIn,setIsSignIn]=useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <SignInScreen signInHandler={setIsSignIn}/>
    </div>  
     )
   };
```

sign in

```
const submitLogin = async (props) => {         
    try {
        const data = await axios.post(apiUrl, {username: email, password: password, auth: auth})
        const token = data.data.data.jwt
        //I need to change isSignedIn to true from App.js here  
        props.signInHandler(true);           
    }
    catch (err) {
        setMessage('Invalid credentials. Please try again.')
    }
}
```